# Can i do judo or jiu-jitsu even if I have braces?

Tags: judo, jujutsu

I'm just wondering if is it okay to be training mix martial arts even if I have braces. Because of the various throws and submission techniques, I'm just wondering if it would be bad for my braces or not. Thanks for whoever can answer my question.

Comment: Do not seek the advice of strangers on the Internet with regards to medical conditions: **Talk to medical professionals**. Your orthodontist should be able to answer (or at least research) said question.

Comment: Three people agree that it's a bad question, but only one VTC?

Answer (score 6):

According to this dentist, the recommendation by the American Association of Orthodontists is that anyone with braces should wear a mouth guard whenever doing a sport, including boxing, wrestling, and martial arts:

http://www.gechofforthodontics.com/mouthguards

I would assume this recommendation is for "all the time" during practice, not just for sparring. So when you walk into that MMA class, put in the mouth guard. Only take it out when you're done with class. That way, no surprise trips to the dentist!

You can get mouth guards that mold to a custom fit. You heat them up in hot water, then stick them in your mouth, bite down, take them out, and let it cool. It will mold to your teeth, braces and all. That's what you want for the best fit.

Do some research on the web to find out what's the best type of mouth guard for you.

I think so long as you're diligent about wearing your mouth guard in class, you probably won't have any damage to your braces. For extra precaution, you can think about concentrating in grappling classes instead of MMA or anything with striking until you get your braces off. (You still need to wear the mouth guard, though.) Either that or tell your MMA partners that you want very light contact to your face or no contact at all.

By the way, throws aren't a problem for braces. None of the throws you'll practice will land you on your face or jaw. If that happens, it would be a rare accident. It can still happen, but it's very unlikely. More likely (but still not very likely), you'll get taken down, and on the way down, you can slam your face or jaw against someone's knee, shoulder, or head. That happens. Just be careful. And always wear that mouth guard.

And as always, run it by your dentist / orthodontist before you do anything. Who knows, maybe you have special braces that require a gentler touch.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Like any sport, wear the correct protective gear especially a mouth guard, train with a qualified instructor and exercise a bit of common sense between yourself and your training partner. If you are experiencing any discomfort,pain or are not confident in the situation, stop immediately.
I train with several guys that are in the same boat and have had no problems following these basic principles.